# What does "Your submission will be handled by Receiving Editor" mean?

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted a paper to a journal and after 20 days I got an email which states

> Your submission entitled "X" will be handled by Receiving Editor.

What does this mean?

Comment: It looks like a confirmation that the paper will be handled by a certain editor. I would say it is basically a confirmation of submission.

Comment: Another possibly related question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/45543

Comment: @Christian thank you, i am still confused to know what it means. Do you think it is an indication that the journal wants to invite reviewers?

Comment: To me it looks like they assigned an editor who will then decide whether to send it to reviewers. It might be that the paper passed some managing editor but I think it is impossible to tell from this message alone.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.nature.com/cdd/authors-and-referees/editorial-process#:~:text=If%20the%20Editor%20decides%20the,availability%20of%20the%20reviewers%20selected.) one journal spelling out the receiving editor's role at their journal. The journal you submitted to might or might not use the title in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Anyon thank you, i guess it is just an editor assignment for my paper. In your mentioned link it means that the paper will be sent out for review and i don't know if it applies to my journal or not.